# Hide aspx button in code behind

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to hide an aspx button on page load if another element has a certain value.

Button:

```
<input type="button" class="formButton" id="btnShowTerminate" value="Terminate Credential" onclick="ToggleTerminationRow()">
```

My issue is that I don't know how to edit the buttons attributes (to make it hidden) in the code behind.

Comment: Well, for starters, there's nothing you can do in the code behind without first making it `runat="server"`

Comment: Also, the button shown is just an html button, not an aspx:Button...

Answer (score 0):

In code behind (on PageLoad event):

```
Page.btnShowTerminate.Visible = false;
```

Comment: I get this error when trying this: Error 1 'System.Web.UI.Page' does not contain a definition for 'btnShowTerminate' and no extension method 'btnShowTerminate' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.Page' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Did you add attrbute `runat="server"` to the control?

Answer (score 0):

HTML controls need to be given the `runat="server"` attribute in order to be used in the server-side code.

To hide the button from your code behind, use an If statement to test if your 'other element' has the required value.

**C#**

```
If(exampleElement.Value == "example value")
{
     Page.btnShowTerminate.Visible = false;   
}
```

**VB**

```
If exampleElement.Value == "example value"

     Page.btnShowTerminate.Visible = false;   
End If
```

This error -

> 'System.Web.UI.Page' does not contain a definition for
>   'btnShowTerminate' and no extension method 'btnShowTerminate'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.Page' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

is because you haven't included `runat="server"` in your input.

The `exampleElement.Value` may have to be different depending on what type of element `exampleElement` is. For example, `Value` will work with a `TextBox` , but you would need to use `InnerHtml` for a `div`

Comment: I get this error when trying to include the page namespace: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Page' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: That's because I've been stupid. Apologies. Remove `using System.Page;` and let me know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Although, a button (any control for that matter) can be hidden from code behind by setting the Visible property to false, there is subtle, and dangerous nuance to that.  Doing this causes the button not only to be hidden, but the resulting HTML button will not render on the page.  Should you have JavaScript that is referencing the button, the JavaScript will fail because the button does not exist on the rendered page.  In debugging, the bug will be caught, but if the JavaScript is never exercised until the code is deployed to a server, it will fail there but no exception will be thrown.  The code just won't work and there will be no indication as to why!

The safe way to hide the button is setting the Style as follows:

```
 btnName.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

This way the button will be rendered but hidden and JavaScript will be able to find it.